# Django Serializers with Foreign Key not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-3.6

I want to create a ListCreateView for my models. 
Here is are models -

```
from django.db import models

from training_service.models.advertiser import Advertiser

class Config(models.Model):
    CONFIG_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('DATA_DESCRIPTOR', 'DATA_DESCRIPTOR'),
        ('DATAFETCH', 'DATAFETCH'),
        ('BATCHSYSTEM', 'BATCHSYSTEM'),
        ('SPARKSYSTEM', 'SPARKSYSTEM')
    )

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    config_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                   choices=CONFIG_TYPE_CHOICES,
                                   blank=False)
    default_value = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'config'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class AdvertiserConfig(models.Model):
    advertiser_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Advertiser, to_field="advertiser_id", db_column="advertiser_id", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    config_id = models.ForeignKey(Config, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'advertiser_config'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Below are the serializers for the models -

```
class ConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Config
        fields = ('name', 'config_type', 'value_type', 'default_value')

class AdvertiserConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    config_name = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = AdvertiserConfig
        fields = ('advertiser_id', 'config_name', 'value')
```

But this is not working when I do a get on AdvertiserConfig I am not getting config_name in the response. And no error is thrown.

Any idea what is wrong here? 
Also how would I do a create for AdvertiserConfig?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need to use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` here, you can simply do this:

```
class AdvertiserConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AdvertiserConfig
        fields = ('advertiser_id', 'config_id', 'value')
```

If you just want a field with config_name, then you can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class AdvertiserConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    config_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = AdvertiserConfig
        fields = ('advertiser_id', 'config_name', 'value')

    def get_config_name(self, obj):
         return obj.config_id.name  # will return config_id's name
```

Also, please consider renaming your model's FK. Because when you use ForignKey with name `config`, django creates a column in DB with name `config_id` which points to Config Model.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the problem for listing. But it still doesn't work for creating a new advertiserconfig. I tried over-writing the create function but it doesn't have config_name as part of the validated_data dictionary. :/

Comment: `SerializerMethodFIeld` is a read only method. So you will see the value when you make a `GET` request. But if you want to write the value, then you have use the first solution. There you need to input the value of `config_id` which is the PK of the Config Model. But if you want to use `config_id` as both read and write with value `name`, then you need to use `SlugRelatedField`. But you need to ensure `name` value is unique

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the name of the config, you can user SlugRelatedField

```
class AdvertiserConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
config = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', read_only=True, many=True)
class Meta:
    model = AdvertiserConfig
    fields = ('advertiser_id', 'config', 'value')
```

And follow ruddras hint to rename your models FK.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I already tried it before posting it here.

Comment: I figured out my issue with SlugRelatedField. I config_name did not have a unique constraint on it. Now it works for GET requests. Thank you. But it still doesn't work for POST for creating / updating an entry.

Comment: For a working POST request u have to use it like config =  AdvertiserConfigSerializer(many=True) and override the save method to save both models. But then u won't GET only config.name but hole config data.